# Show $I_b \subseteq I_a$ when $b \leq a$

Tags: set-theory

I am currently working on the following problem:

Let A be any nonempty set, $p(A)$ be the power set of A, $F$ be a function from $p(A)$ to $p(A)$ that is monotone, meaning that whenever $X \subseteq Y$ then $F(X) \subseteq F(Y)$.

By transfinite induction define a set $I_a \subseteq A$ for every ordinal $a$ as follows:

$I_a$ = empty set if $a$ = 0

$I_a$ = $F(I_b)$ if $a$ = $b+1$

$I_a$ = $\cup_(b\leq a)$

Show $I_b \subseteq I_a$ when $b \leq a$

My question is this:

Would it not be enough to cite the successor case in transfinite induction as enough to prove that statement?

Or is this question asking me to prove the successor case?

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is no. You also have to take care of the limit ordinal case to have a complete proof.

*And by the way, there is probably a typo in your question. I suspect that
$$I_b = \bigcup_{b\leq a} I_a$$ in case of a limit ordinal.*